# How-to get "redundant tiles" into MBTiles's sqlight tile view?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mbtiles

At [MBTiles Link](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/) there is a section:

> Using views to reference redundant images
>   MBTiles can reduce the amount of space used by these redundant tiles drastically by implementing the tiles table as a view

If I have z/x/y folder of png tiles how to i get the "mbutil" to import identical png images
into the tiles view? Or would I have to do it by myself after "mbutil" has done its import into sqlite? if yes are there any scripts available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `mbutil` does not support compression like TileMill does - [the code is there](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/blob/master/mbutil/util.py#L71), but not connected to the executable you get when you install it. An enterprising Python developer could do the wiring to make it possible; otherwise, TileMill is the main application that outputs compressed MBTiles.

Comment: without knowing python I just added compression_prepare(cur,con)
    compression_do(cur,con,9500)
    compression_finalize(cur)
    optimize_database(con) to the end of disk_to_mbtiles and got a save of about 400 Kb on the resulting mbtiles file. I think I need to find a way to better get duplicate tiles with almost the same pixels...Many thanks!